# Method doWork() not calling with WorkManager

Tags: android, androidx, android-workmanager

I need to upload file from device to my app. I use WorkManager to do it in background.

After updating library from `android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0-alpha04` to `androidx.work:work-runtime:2.0.0` something goes wrong.

Method `doWork()` not calling in my `UploadFileTask(workerParams: WorkerParameters) : Worker(Application.getContext(), workerParams)`

Here is how I run my uploading:

```
fun upload(id: String, file: File, params: FileStorage.DocParams?, additionalTag: String): File {
    cancelUploadIfWas(file)
    fileStorage.save(file, params)
    val inputData = Data.Builder().putString(FileTask.PATH_KEY, file.path).build()
    val uploadWork = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(UploadFileTask::class.java)
        .addTag(ID_PREFIX + id)
        .addTag(PATH_PREFIX + file.path)
        .addTag(UPLOAD_TAG)
        .addTag(additionalTag)
        .keepResultsForAtLeast(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .setInputData(inputData)
        .build()

    workManager.enqueue(uploadWork)
    file.uploadStatus.onLoading()
    file.uploadWork=uploadWork
    uploadingFiles.put(ID_PREFIX + id, file)
    workManager.getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(uploadWork.id).observe(this, uploadObserver)
    return file
}
```

But my `uploadObserver` receives  `State.FAILED` exactly after `State.ENQUEUED`

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Version 2.0.0 is for androidx only, do you use it instead of the support libraries?

Comment: @ronginat yes, I have already updated all my support libraries to AndroidX

Comment: Perhaps there is a problem in your `UploadFileTask` implementation.

Comment: Is there any particular reason to set four different Tag to identify your WorkRequest?
You're then setting a minimum duration for keeping the result around equal to 0. This seems dangerous as it may be pruned before you can query for its status. What it's the reason to set it to 0?

Comment: Thx to everybody, solved the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solved**

The trick was in that we have to create out task by this way:

```
UploadFileTask(context: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) : Worker(context, workerParams)
```

The constructor of our task have to receive exactly two parameters: `context: Context` and `workerParams: WorkerParameters`

Explanation:

```
val downloadWork = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(downloadingTask)
            .addTag(ID_TAG)
            .keepResultsForAtLeast(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build()

workManager.enqueue(downloadWork)
```

`WorkManager` expects to receive `downloadWork` which was biult with `downloadingTask`, that has exactly two params in its constructor

Comment: Could you be specific? What exactly was the change u did? I also have this two param constructor, but neither the constructor is called nor dowork() !!! could you tell me pls!!

Comment: @adi
First I did like this:
```UploadFileTask(workerParams: WorkerParameters): 
 Worker(Application.getContext(), workerParams)```

There was not context parameter in my ```UploadFileTask``` constructor.

But in fact system needs both two parameters in task constructor:
```UploadFileTask(context: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) : Worker(context, workerParams)```

Comment: @adi I added an explanation to my answer

Comment: Thanks for the inputs.I have posted a question regarding this.If possible kindly have a look at it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60644939/android-workmanager-not-starting-the-worker

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to check the size of your payload/data that you're sending to your worker? 
Sometimes when your data object is too large for the worker limits, the `doWork()` may not be called.

Or, it could be some exception thrown in your `doWork()` method without you noticing it, so it's failing to proceed with further code executions.

You can try to:

- Remove `setInputData()` from your upload method
- Remove `getInputData()` from your WorkManager class
- Now a `Log` to your `doWork()` method to check if it's being called

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. The issue was caused with that I used only one param in my Task constructor: ```UploadFileTask(context: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) : Worker(context, workerParams)```. There is some reflection under the hood in WorkManager, so the number of params in constructor matters.

Comment: Yes, this must affect the Worker too..